# Why does data.table `:=` not work when used with `sample`?

Tags: r, data.table

In attempting to take random samples from groups in a data table I attempted to use a dummy column with `sample(c(1, rep(0, .N-1)))` but something seems to go horribly wrong in the `data.table` when I do this

**Example**

```
> library(data.table)
> set.seed(151)
> DT = data.table(L = rep(c("A","B", "C"), 4), X = rnorm(12), i = 1:12)
> DT[, S := sample(c(1, rep(0, .N-1))), by = L]
> DT[S==1]
   L          X i S
1: C -0.1467396 3 1
2: A -1.3974781 7 1
3: B -1.0188383 8 1
> 
> DT[, S := sample(c(2, rep(0, .N-1))), by = L]
> DT[S==2]
   L          X  i S
1: A  0.6721730 10 2
2: B -0.4845518 11 0
3: C  0.5606090 12 2
> 
> DT[, S := sample(c(3, rep(0, .N-1))), by = L]
> DT[S==3]
   L          X  i S
1: B -0.4845518 11 3
2: C  0.5606090 12 3
> 
> DT
    L           X  i S
 1: A -0.05153895  1 0
 2: B  0.76573738  2 0
 3: C -0.14673959  3 0
 4: A -0.11318581  4 3
 5: B -0.39551140  5 0
 6: C  0.78227595  6 0
 7: A -1.39747811  7 0
 8: B -1.01883832  8 0
 9: C  0.22947586  9 0
10: A  0.67217297 10 0
11: B -0.48455178 11 3
12: C  0.56060896 12 3
>
```

As you can see, not only is it not inserting the correct number of 1s each attempt, but also `DT[S==1]` no longer functions correctly, somehow returning rows where S is not 1.

What is going on here?

It is perhaps worth noting that the FIRST time it is called, it seems to work correctly - so this suggests something odd is going on with the group assign over the top of an existing column.

Comment: This is a known issue with the version on CRAN. Set `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`.